# use a custom uiview inside a storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

So, I am using `storyboard` and I have dragged inside my `UIViewController` a `UIView`.

Let's call it customView, and it's class is called `SPView`. The class is set in the inspector window. Inside the `SPView.h` there are a number of properties

I have tried the following :

1. If I drag a label inside the `UIView` (in the `storyboard`), the label is shown, but I cannot connect it to one of my outlets in the `SPView.h` by drag and drop.
2. If I create a new XIB file, with the label inside, I can do the connections as I like.

Then inside my `UIViewController` I have tried either of these:

```
self.customView =[[SPView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 60, 200, 260)]
self.customView =[[SPView alloc]init];
```

and inside my SPView, if I use this:

```
 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
 NSLog(@"initWitchCoder called");
 if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
 //[self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SPView" owner:self     options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
 [self baseInit];
 }
```

the label is not shown.

If I uncomment the comment, the `initWithCoder` is called for ever and the app eventually crashes.

What I want is :

to have a custom `UIView` inside a `UIViewController`, set either in the storyboard or programmatically (but it will be better if the graphic data are set in `storyboard` or in a separate .XIB file so as to inspect them more easily).

Can you help me on that?

Comment: for connecting to an `outlet` in your `SPView.h` change the class of your custom view from `UIView` to `SPView` in `storyboard`.

Comment: So your problem here is that you can't connect the `UILabel` to the `SPView`'s outlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot drag outlets to custom class uiview class . only its allowed when using xib.
you can drop outlets of that custom view in its parent viewcontroller only. 
you can set tags in subviews of your custom view. and can easily access them by using this below code .
 **lets say you have a subview in your custom view with tag :2**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
 NSLog(@"initWitchCoder called");
 if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
 //[self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SPView" owner:self     options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
        UILabel *lbl  = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:2];
 [self baseInit];
 }
```

so you  had to set tags to subviews to access them

in your uiviewcontroller you had to drop outlet directly . no need for this
like this it will be initialized automatically

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet SPView *customView; //right and easy way

X    self.customView =[[SPView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 60, 200, 260)]
X    self.customView =[[SPView alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have following method defined in your UIViewController class and have an XIB created for SPView.

```
- (SPView*) loadCustomViewFromNib
{
  SPView *spView = nil;

  NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SPView" 
                                               owner:nil 
                                             options:nil];
  for (id object in array)
  {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[SPView class]])
    {
        spView = (SPView*)object;
        break;
    }
 }

 return spView;
}
```

And have SPView initialized as shown below

```
self.customView = [self loadCustomViewFromNib];
```